# Test error: how to use :id?

Tags: testing, clojure, h2, luminus, hugsql

I'm trying to do this for the first time in `luminus`, `h2`, `hugsql` and `clojure`.

The `insert` statement works fine when entered in a SQL client connected to the `h2`database, but fails in code.   It seems it has to do with the `WHERE id = :id` clause of the `get-assessor` query, but can't find a way to do this.

In file `./resources/sql/queries.sql`

```
-- :name get-assessor :? :1
-- :doc retrieve a assessor given the id.
SELECT * FROM assessores
WHERE id = :id

-- :name save-assessor! :n
-- :doc creates new assessor
INSERT INTO assessores
    (first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    phone,
    address1,
    address2,
    post_code,
    post_code_city,
    birth_date,
    tax_number,
    to_buy,
    to_sell,
    to_career,
    first_message,
    is_active)
VALUES (:first_name,
    :last_name,
    :email,
    :phone,
    :address1,
    :address2,
    :post_code,
    :post_code_city,
    :birth_date,
    :tax_number,
    :to_buy,
    :to_sell,
    :to_career,
    :first_message,
    :is_active)
```

In file: `./test/db/core.clj`

```
(deftest test-assessores
  (jdbc/with-db-transaction [t-conn *db*]
    (jdbc/db-set-rollback-only! t-conn)
    (let [timestamp (java.util.Date.)]
      (is (= 1 (db/save-assessor!
                 t-conn
                 {:first_name "Bob"
          :last_name            "Singer"
          :email                "lpe@gmail.com"
          :phone                "888232418"
          :address1             "10 st"
          :address2             "VNC"
          :post_code            "9990-990"
          :post_code_city       "Cer"
          :birth_date           "1962-06-06"
          :tax_number           204559449
          :to_buy               true
          :to_sell              false
          :to_career            false
          :first_message        "how to buy?"
          :is_active            true}
                 {:connection t-conn})))

      (is (=
           {:first_name "Bob"
          :last_name            "Singer"
          :email                "lpe@gmail.com"
          :phone                "888232418"
          :address1             "10 st"
          :address2             "VNC"
          :post_code            "9990-990"
          :post_code_city       "Cer"
          :birth_date           "1962-06-06"
          :tax_number           204559449
          :to_buy               true
          :to_sell              false
          :to_career            false
          :first_message        "how to buy?"
          :is_active            true}
           (-> (db/get-assessor t-conn {})
               (first)
               (select-keys [:first_name ])))))))
```

The messages returned (truncated) are:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Method is only allowed for a query. Use execute or executeUpdate instead of executeQuery; SQL statement:
                              INSERT INTO assessores
                                (first_name,
                                last_name,
                                email,
                                phone,
                                address1,
                                address2,
                                post_code,
                                post_code_city,
                                birth_date,
                                tax_number,
                                to_buy,
                                to_sell,
                                to_career,
                                first_message,
                                is_active)
                              VALUES ( ? ,
                                ? ,
                                ? ,
                                ? ,
                                ? ,
                                ? ,
                                ? ,
                                ? ,
                                ? ,
                                ? ,
                                ? ,
                                ? ,
                                ? ,
                                ? ,
                                ? ) [90002-192]
                SQL: "INSERT INTO assessores\n\t(first_name,\n\tlast_name,\n\temail,\n\tphone,\n\taddress1,\n\taddress2,\n\tpost_code,\n\tpost_code_city,\n\tbirth_date,\n\ttax_number,\n\tto_buy,\n\tto_sell,\n\tto_career,\n\tfirst_message,\n\tis_active)\nVALUES ( ? ,\n\t? ,\n\t? ,\n\t? ,\n\t? ,\n\t? ,\n\t? ,\n\t? ,\n\t? ,\n\t? ,\n\t? ,\n\t? ,\n\t? ,\n\t? ,\n\t? )"
           SQLState: "90002"
          errorCode: 90002
    originalMessage: "Method is only allowed for a query. Use execute or executeUpdate instead of executeQuery"

ERROR in (test-assessores) (core.clj:4617)

clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Parameter Mismatch: :id parameter data not found.

Testing orio.test.handler
(...)
Ran 2 tests containing 4 assertions.
0 failures, 2 errors.
Tests failed.
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
-- :name save-assessor! :n
```

should be

```
-- :name save-assessor! :! :n
```

see:  https://www.hugsql.org/#command

the command defaults to `:?` which indicates that it is a non-modifying query.  For insert/update statements, a `:!` should be used in the definition.

Edit:
After some more information has been given -- it looks like `(get-assessor)` is looking for a parameter of `:id` (as can be seen by your definition in the HUGSql file.

I would create a new query in that file. Something like `(get-first-assessor)`

`-- :name get-first-assessor :? :1
-- :doc get the first assessor in the system, ordred by id
SELECT * FROM assessores
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1`

Then replace your call to `(get-assessor t-conn {})` with `(get-first-assessor t-conn {})` in your test

Comment: My fault with that `:!` missing, but it didn't solve the issue.  `lein test` still complains about the `:id`.   I presume it's about the `WHERE` clause of the `get-assessor` method that is called in the test.  But I don't know how to deal with it in `deftest test-assessores`.

Comment: Your call to `get-assessor` is not passing in a value for `:id`.  You must pass in a hashmap with `:id` specified:  `(get-assessor tconn {:id 2})`  If, instead, you are trying to get the generated ID that you just inserted, please read "Retrieving Last Inserted ID or Record" under this section: https://www.hugsql.org/#using-insert

Comment: @CurtisSummers, @aholt  The `hugsql` link you provided (that I'd previously read) show an example when a `id` is inserted manually, not when is is autoincremented as in my example.

Comment: @aholt  Use the same example but without ids.  It should still return generated keys.

Comment: @CurtisSummers  Do you mean I should take the `WHERE id = :id` from the `get-assessor` query?  Or elsewhere?

Comment: according to your sql, get-assessor needs to have an {:id} in the parameters.  I see you are calling get-assessor without that.  Probably the problem.  You probably need to add a new query.  I'll update my answer